# How do I do this query using JPA so that it is not very slow?

Tags: java, orm, jpa

How do you join across multiple tables in an efficient way using JPQL

```
select a.text,b.text,c.text,
from Class1 a, Class2 b, Class3 c
where a.id=b.b_id and b.id=c.b_id and a.text like ... and b.text like ...
```

I am doing something like this, the tables only have a few thousand rows, yet the query takes 5-6 seconds to run. I assume it is joining all of the tables before doing the filter

I know the speed may be JPA vendor implementation specific, but I suspect this is not the proper way to write this query!

Comment: What does the "BAD" generated SQL looks like?

Answer (score 1):

See what SQL query has been generated. Then `EXPLAIN` that query and try to optimize it. For example, make sure you have proper indices.

Comment: The problem is that the JPA query is converting to bad SQL. I want to know how to make JPA generate better SQL.

Comment: first see _what_ SQL has been generated, and then assume it's bad.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't like the SQL which JPA is generating (but I doubt its generating "bad" SQL) you can always use a [Native Query](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/EntityManager.html#createNativeQuery%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Class%29).